# Add Django super user token in http request

Tags: django, http, django-rest-framework, django-views, authorization

I use Django (as backend and frontend) for a website. I want to create http request with the condition (of use) to be Django super user. But I don't know how to add in the headers the token (or the proof that the user that uses the request is a super user).
I tried this with the csrf token :
First I use the `{% csrf_token %}` in the template.

```html
<form action="#" id="admin-add-event" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
        ...
    <button type="submit" id="admin-submit">Add event</button>
</form>
```

```js
const url = `${window.BASE_URL}events/`;
    const form = document.getElementById('admin-add-event');
    const data = {
        ...
    }

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', url , true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', form.elements.csrfmiddlewaretoken.value);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.onload = function () {
        ...
    }
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

And in the Django view of the endpoint :

```py
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def all_events(request):
   
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        # etc ...
```

But the check of super user fails always

I precise that I don't want to implemente a user system. I want to use the system of super user of Django.

Thanks in advance !